# How can I use sleep for cursor method to avoid rate limiting?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, rate-limiting

I'm trying to get all of a user's follower ids (75K+) without hitting the rate limit. I figured you can put a sleep method on the cursor to prevent over 15 calls per 15 minutes. Any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the [`twitter`](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/RateLimiting.md) gem for interacting with the Twitter API. There is exactly your scenario described in [one](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/RateLimiting.md) of their wikis:

```
follower_ids = client.follower_ids('justinbieber')
begin
  follower_ids.to_a
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
  # NOTE: Your process could go to sleep for up to 15 minutes but if you
  # retry any sooner, it will almost certainly fail with the same exception.
  sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
  retry
end
```

The idea is to simply `sleep` an amount of time if the rate limit has been reached, then `retry` the API call.

If you would like to avoid the rate limiting altogether, you can take `limit - 1` elements from the returned cursor every `x` seconds. In your case, take 15 elements, then sleep for 15 minutes. Here's an example:

```
follower_ids = client.follower_ids('justinbieber')
loop do
  follower_ids.take(15)
  break if follower_ids.last?
  sleep 15 * 60 # 15 minutes
end
```

Comment: won't that hit the rate limit? I'm trying to avoid hitting the rate limit.

Comment: how can you use `.last?` method if it's private?

Comment: It shouldn't be private. I checked the docs over here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter#Cursors

Comment: Ok. Well I used your code and it still gets a rate limit. I think its from the first line in your code ...for some reason :\

Comment: The first line just returns a cursor and iterating over it will actually trigger API requests. You can debug step-by-step and see what happens; you'll better understand both your code and the twitter gem.

Comment: okie doke, what i should use to debug? ..I would like to know where i can put a sleep on the curor so it doesn't hit the rate limit unnecessarily.

Comment: You can start debugging right before the loop, then step into it and see what happens on each iteration. `byebug` is a good choice (or `debugger` if you're using Ruby <2.0).